# where to do input validation

Tags: validation, input

Suppose the business layer is consumed by web and some of the business layer's functionality is open to public also as REST web services.

Would you do input validation for business logic at presentation layer (web or REST web service) or in business layer and capture the validation errors (thrown by business layer) at presentation layer?

(Specifically spring framework is in use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, it is generally better to put business logic (incl input validation logic) in the business layer because

- You may be dealing with multiple presentation mediums (e.g., web GUI and API)
- You don't want to repeat code and manage two instances of that logic

Good frameworks will allow you to define such logic in a common place and support catching issues early (e.g., in the presentation layer), which is usually a more intuitive (fail fast), more scalable (front end catches it) solution.

However, if your framework(s) do not support this capability, you should prefer consistency and maintainability and put the logic in the business layer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out these Kelly. I agree on these however the problem is, I think, I may just reject invalid inputs (throw a validation error etc) at business layer, but at presentation layer I may need a more fine grained validation errors (field a and field b separately etc.). To do that, I have to put all validation in the finest possible grain to business layer, then behave accordingly in presentation layer, isnt it so ? I am thinking in terms of spring, and I am not sure I found a clear solution. I am new to spring so I may be missing a point. Any clarification is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend implementing validation in all layters. I do the UI so the user experience is high, with immediate feedback. But I never trust the data provided by the UI (think a user who disables JS). Now how detailed your server-side validation goes is up to you. But you want to avoid having your user have to suffer through a full round trip to the server if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Violations of business rules should always happen in the business layer. Whether you allow for proactive checking or not is a design decision, as is whether you want to do eager checking on the client to avoid round-trips.